# Parsley 2.0 remote not triggered on submit

Tags: jquery, validation, parsley.js

I use remote validation for user registration to check is email already used and it works ok on change but validation is not triggered on submit. So if users enters email that is already used he will get error message but when he submits request that error is ignored and ajax call will is executed.

This is my email input:

```
<div id="userPanel">
     ...
     <input id="emailInput" class="form-control" type="text" name="email" data-parsley-type="email" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-trigger="change" data-parsley-remote="@Url.Action("CheckIsEmailUnique", "Onboarding")" data-parsley-remote-message="Email must be unique."/>
     ...
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var parsleyForm = $('#userPanel').parsley();
$("#saveNewUser").click(function () {
        var isValid = parsleyForm.validate();
        if (isValid) {
               ...
               ajaxCall(...);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Parsley.remote.js, two new methods are available: `asyncValidate()` and `asyncIsValid()` that returns promises.

Parsley.remote.js auto-bind `asyncValidate()` on `data-parsley-trigger` events and on form submit.

If you want to manually control parsley on form submit via javascript, please use this:

```
var parsleyForm = $('#userPanel').parsley();
$("#saveNewUser").click(function () {
    parsleyForm.asyncValidate()
      .done(function () { console.log('success'); })
      .fail(function () { console.log('there is an error'); })
      .always(function () { console.log('done everytime whatever happens'); });
}
```

Comment: From those callback, how do we retrieve the Ajax data ? It's useless in the above form...